# What is the purpose of `_OgreExport` on class declaration in Ogre3D?

Tags: c++, class, declaration

Looking through the Ogre3D source code, I see many of the classes declared like so:

```
class _OgreExport RenderTarget : public RenderSysAlloc
```

Could someone help me understand what "_OgreExport" is doing there?

Comment: Guess it is only on windows...

Comment: @texasbruce no, see my answer; it's not only related to windows anymore.

Comment: @JohnSavage see my (pdated) answer for a more detailed explanation regarding the macro.

Answer (score 3):

#### SHORT SUMMARY

The macro `_OgreExport` is defined to conditionally apply *visibility status* to the declared class, it will expand to different *implementation-specific* attributes on different platforms.

---

#### WORKING UNDER A `*NIX` RELATED PLATFORM?

The definition of the macro `_OgreExport` can be found in [ogreplatform.h](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/OgrePlatform_8h_source.html), it's mentioned on line [248](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/OgrePlatform_8h_source.html#l00248) (and other places)

```
246 // Enable GCC symbol visibility
247 # if defined( OGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY )
248 #         define _OgreExport __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
249 #         define _OgrePrivate __attribute__ ((visibility("hidden")))
250 # else
251 #         define _OgreExport
252 #         define _OgrePrivate
253 # endif
```

---

If `OGRE_GCC_VISIBILITY` has been defined it expands to `__attribute__((visibility("default"))`.

`visibility` is is an gcc specific attribute that can be read about in the wiki on *gcc.gnu.org* on the [page regarding Visbility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). That pages sums it out in a very clear, and easily understood manner.

In short, to quote the above linked page, it says:

> - **Why is the new C++ visibility support so useful?**
>
>   Put simply, it hides most of the ELF symbols which would have previously (and unnecessarily) been public.

---

#### WHAT ABOUT WINDOWS?

On windows the [macro is expanded](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/OgrePlatform_8h_source.html#l00188) to `__declspec(...)`, which is applied for similar reasons as the described regarding the visibility in *gcc*.

- [msdn.com - Using __declspec(dllimport) and __declspec(dllexport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)